# How to update D365 multi-select picklist to an empty value (no selections) using OData?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, odata

We have a custom field in an entity in Microsoft Dynamics 365 (dataverse). It's a multi-select picklist, so the OData API exposes it as a string (comma-separated value).

Setting values to the field is easy, we just set the string to a value, e.g. "1, 2, 3" and save.

But if we want to clear all selections (the field is set to "Optional"), then we get an error `"Edm Object passed should have the options selected"`.

I've tried sending just a space, but then I get an error `"The optionset values sent   are not valid integers."`

I cannot find any examples in the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/multi-select-picklist?view=op-9-1)

**So how do I clear the pick list from selected values using OData API and Microsoft OData Client (.NET)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dynamics 365 CE / Dynamics CRM / Dataverse, if you want to clear a field you set it to `null`, this is valid for all types including multi-select optionsets (Choices)

Comment: Of course, I was sending an empty string and it didn't work!